# How to store the line numbers of the lines containing a specific string in a text file in an environment variable?

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, findstr, line-numbers

I currently have this batch code that tells me the amount of times this string comes up in a text file.

```
@ECHO OFF
set /a Numb=0
for /f %%i in ('FINDSTR /N .* %1') do (set /a Numb+=1)
echo %Numb%
```

I need another piece of code that outputs the line numbers that the text is on to a variable.

How to store the line numbers of the lines containing a specific string in a text file in an environment variable?

Comment: have you tried checking the output of `FINDSTR /N .* %1` ?

Comment: Yes but I need that stored into a variable.

Comment: This batch code is for getting the number of lines in a text file specified as first argument on calling the batch file. It does not search for any string and therefore does not return the number of found lines containing the searched string. So what do you really want? Run in a command prompt window `findstr /?` and `for /?` for help on the standard Windows console application __FINDSTR__ and Windows command processor internal command __FOR__.

Comment: What? The code i put their has nothing to do with what I want it was just a example?

Comment: All I need is a code that stores the line numbers of a specific string in a text file to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My batch code for this task which requires the specification of file name and search string as arguments on running the batch file with some error checking:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FileName=%~1"
set "Search=%~2"

rem Exit batch file if the two required arguments were not specified.
if "%FileName%" == "" (
    echo Error: There is no file name specified as first parameter.
    goto ErrorOuput
)

if "%Search%" == "" (
    echo Error: There is no search string specified as second parameter.
    goto ErrorOuput
)

if not exist "%FileName%" (
    echo Error: The file "!FileName!" does not exist.
    goto ErrorOuput
)

set "LineNumbers="
for /F "delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /N /C:"%Search%" "%FileName%" 2^>nul') do set "LineNumbers=!LineNumbers!,%%I"

if "%LineNumbers%" == "" (
    echo Info: The string "!Search!" could not be found in "!FileName!"
    goto EndBatch
)

rem Remove the comma from begin of list of line numbers.
set "LineNumbers=!LineNumbers:~1!"

echo Found "!Search!" in "!FileName!" on the lines:
echo.
echo %LineNumbers%
goto EndBatch

:ErrorOuput
echo.
echo Usage: %~nx0 "file name" "search string"

:EndBatch
echo.
endlocal
pause
```

The error checking is not complete. There can still errors occur. For example the first argument could be `*.txt` which would produce a wrong result as **FINDSTR** outputs in this case first the file name, then a colon, next the line number, and one more colon instead of just line number and colon like when searching on a single file.

Run at least once in a command prompt window for example

```
findstr /I /L /N /C:"endbatch" "SearchString.bat"
```

with above batch code stored in file `SearchString.bat` in current directory to see what command **FOR** processes here.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~1` and `%~2`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` to redirect the error message output by **FINDSTR** to handle **STDERR** to device **NUL** to suppress it if the searched string could not be found in search file. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with `^` to apply the redirection on execution of **FINDSTR** instead of interpreting `2>nul` as redirection for command **FOR** at an invalid position in command line.

Comment: for a more comprehensive answer than mine +1 :)

Comment: One extra question? Is their a easy way to use a wild card like .* for the search variable?

Comment: @ProgrammerNZ You have not opened a command prompt window, run `findstr /?` and read the output help, aren't you? Yes, you can use a regular expression search string instead of a literal search string by using `/R` (regular) instead of `/L` (literal). But the regular expression search string should be something better than `.*`. This means any character except newline characters 0 or more times. This search expression is always true on each line. That explains why your code is just counting the lines as `.*` is true even on empty lines not containing any character at all.

Comment: Thanks I will try that

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I store the line numbers of matching lines for a string in a text file?

Use the following batch file.

**test.cmd:**

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set line_numbers=
for /f "skip=2 delims=[]" %%i in ('find /n /i "%1" names.txt') do (
  set line_numbers=!line_numbers! %%i
  )
rem skip leading space
echo %line_numbers:~1%
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Pass search string as an argument to `test.cmd`.
- The file being searched is `names.txt` (you could pass this as a parameter as well).
- The match line numbers are add to the variable `line_numbers`.

**Example usage:**

```
F:\test>type names.txt
Joe Bloggs, 123 Main St, Dunoon
Arnold Jones, 127 Scotland Street, Edinburgh
Joe Bloggs, 123 Main St, Dunoon
Arnold Jones, 127 Scotland Street, Edinburgh
Joe Bloggs, 123 Main St, Dunoon
Arnold Jones, 127 Scotland Street, Edinburgh
F:\test>test bloggs
1 3 5

F:\test>test jones
2 4 6
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).

Comment: I'm confused on how to use this?

Comment: @ProgrammerNZ Did you read the notes and example usage? What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: For usage of `find` instead of `findstr` and also good explanation +1 :)